# During django unittests, database remains empty

Tags: django, mariadb, pytest

I'm running some unittests that need manual debugging.
Somehow nothing is written to the database during those tests.

Is there any way to force Django (or pytest?) to commit changes directly when executed so I can actually see what is in the database when I hit a breakpoint?

```
my_object = SomeDefaultDjangoModel()
my_object.some_random_text = 'Just adding some data'
my_object.save()

foo = 'bar' <= Hitting breakpoint here.
```

Doing a manual SQL query against my database return 0 rows.
How can I make this work?

*** Update ***

The problem is that Django does not allow you to save changes to the database until the end of every request, which in most cases not an issue.
However, when you want to bypass the ORM and are executing queries using the raw connection, it seems to start a separate database connection for that. As all transactions are pending until the end of the request, it is impossible to access those changes from the other database connection. This returns invalid results and make my unittests fail.

I have not found a way of committing pending transactions (yet), so I guess I will start to write save_raw() methods to my models that do just save the data to the database directly.

Comment: Or you certain that you are querying against your test database? It should be separate from your "normal" database.

Comment: Look at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/advanced/#advanced-features-of-transactiontestcase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass your tests from `TransactionTestCase` instead of `TestCase`, and then the data will be saved/committed as expected, so you can then examine the data in the database directly.

Per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase):

> Django’s `TestCase` class is a more commonly used subclass of
>   `TransactionTestCase` that makes use of database transaction
>   facilities to speed up the process of resetting the database to a
>   known state at the beginning of each test. A consequence of this,
>   however, is that some database behaviors cannot be tested within a
>   Django `TestCase` class. For instance, you cannot test that a block of
>   code is executing within a transaction, as is required when using
>   `select_for_update()`. In those cases, you should use
>   `TransactionTestCase`.
>
> `TransactionTestCase` and `TestCase` are identical except for the manner
>   in which the database is reset to a known state and the ability for
>   test code to test the effects of commit and rollback:
>
> - A `TransactionTestCase` resets the database after the test runs by 
>     truncating all tables. A `TransactionTestCase` may call commit and
>     rollback and observe the effects of these calls on the database.
> - A `TestCase`, on the other hand, does not truncate tables after a test.
>     Instead, it encloses the test code in a database transaction that is
>     rolled back at the end of the test. This guarantees that the rollback
>     at the end of the test restores the database to its initial state.